# Copying static variable in C++ file stream

Tags: c++, class, file-io, static, binaryfiles

I have written a program to delete an *class object stored in a binary file* using c++ file-stream. I have to copy all the objects from one file(example.dat) to another(temp.dat) during this process.

I have a **static variable** as a part of the class and i would like it to be copied to along with the objects. ***But the static variable is not copied to temp.dat and its value in temp.dat is 0*** as the static variable is not part of any object.

Here is the function and class definition I used

```
{                                                  //the problem is in this function
    cout<<"\nSno of record to delete: ";
    int del;
    cin>>del;

        fstream o;
o.open("temp.dat",ios::out|ios::in|ios::binary);

if(!f)
{
    cout<<"File not Found";
    exit(0);
}
else
{f.seekp(0);
    f.read((char*)&dats, sizeof(dats));
    while(!f.eof())
    {
        if(dats.sno!=del)
        {
            o.write((char*)&dats, sizeof(dats));



        }

        f.read((char*)&dats, sizeof(dats));

    }


     }

o.close();
f.close();
remove("date.dat");                       
rename("temp.dat", "date.dat");



return 0; }
```

class definition

```
class date{
int d,m,y;
int k;
char dday[10];
char monthn[10];
char name[50];


public:

int sno;
int odd ();
void getdata();
int fsno();
void display();
static int ID; //static variable
}
```

Please suggest a way around this problem

Answer (score 0):

You should not mix up classes and objects. Static data members are not part of
objects but are part of whole class and shared between all instances
so you have to store and read such separately from individual objects.

For example you can store it at start of file:

```
f.seekp(0);

f.read((char*)&date::ID, sizeof(date::ID));
if (!f) { cout<<"File format bad"; exit(0); }
o.write((char*)&date::ID, sizeof(date::ID));

// go on reading objects
f.read((char*)&dats, sizeof(dats));
// ...
```

Comment: I understand how static members work and it is due to the reasons mentioned in your answer that the variable is not being copied to the file. Can you help me with the code to copy the static variable separately

Comment: Generally it is like all other read and write. depends where in your file you want to store that.